# Simulating Wait handles in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, autoresetevent

We can use `Wait` and `Pulse` to simulate a `ManualResetEvent` as follows:

**code #1**

```
readonly object _locker = new object();
bool _signal;
void WaitOne()
{
  lock (_locker)
   {
     while (!_signal) Monitor.Wait (_locker);
   }
}

void Set()
{ 
   lock (_locker) 
      { _signal = true; 
        Monitor.PulseAll (_locker); 
      }
}

void Reset() 
   {
    lock (_locker) _signal = false; 
   }
```

*fine*

now lets talk about enhancing it to be `AutoREsetEvent` :

an `AutoResetEvent` is simply a matter of replacing the code in `WaitOne` with this:

**code #2**

```
lock (_locker)
{
    while (!_signal) Monitor.Wait (_locker);
    _signal = false;//<---------------
}
```

and replacing `PulseAll` with `Pulse` in the `Set` method:

**code #3**

```
lock (_locker) 
   { _signal = true; 
     Monitor.Pulse (_locker); 
   }
```

and here is the question  : 
at code #2 , the line `_signal = false;`.

why is it necessary ? `Pulse` will only reach **1** wait handle and  I know that `AutoREsetEvent` is letting only one blocked item to go through and automatically close the gate.

so why writing `_signal = false` is necessary ? .

Comment: I have to ask - what is wrong with the ManualResetEvent in System.Threading?

Comment: @MartinJames WaitAll and SignalAndWait won’t run in a single-threaded apartment , and theis one part in a way of solving that issue. http://books.google.co.il/books?id=VENrFSQFco8C&pg=PA840&lpg=PA840&dq=%22WaitAll+and+SignalAndWait+won%E2%80%99t+run+in+a+single-threaded+apartment.+Fortunately%22&source=bl&ots=3uVZnocWcP&sig=FVtdpw4xbrhQdSNOwp-Zo-PVMOU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oNT2T5XfEOiP4gSTuYjKBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22WaitAll%20and%20SignalAndWait%20won%E2%80%99t%20run%20in%20a%20single-threaded%20apartment.%20Fortunately%22&f=false

Comment: Well, they will run fine but will prevent message-processing in your STA:( If a thread must process messages, it's best to signal them by sending them messages.  If you need MRE functionality, can you take it out of the STA and use another thread?  This other MRE-based thread can post messages for communicating with the STA.

Comment: @MartinJames MRE ...?can you explain please ?

Comment: Sorry - ManualResetEvent - it's just a lot of typing <g>  Windows synchro object names seem to go on for ever 'WaitForMultipleObjectsEx' is another painful load of typing. Before long, it will only be sensible to copy/paste the names from MSDN!

Comment: I don't see why you need a lock at all in the Manual version, just make the _signal volatile...

Comment: @bond volatile doesnt garuntee youll have the latest value, as it can change the order of commands in case of write after read ! Its a dangerous command which creates half fences , unlike lock which is a full fence , also you cant use ( imho ) monitor wait without a wrapper lock

Comment: * Read after write . Not write after read

Comment: @RoyiNamir - my idea was not to use Monitor class at all. None of those methods contains both reads and writes in the Manual case, so even if what you say about volatile is true, it wont cause a problem.

Comment: @bond do how would you do signal to waiters : any , all ? Supply explanation sample

Comment: you just do ' _signal = true;' as you do now, and again this is just for the Manual case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `_signal` variable stays `true`, then if another thread calls `WaitOne` *after* the `Set` call, it wouldn't wait. You don't just have to consider how *existing waiting threads* are handled - you have to consider the overall state of the object.

Comment: I guess i was looking only at  1 object , and not the overall process. thanks

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I'm going to write extra chapters covering C# 5, and it may end up as a third edition, but without significant rewriting of the content from the second edition. It's possible that the new chapters will be free for existing owners of the second edition.

Comment: It's 30 quid on Amazon!  There again, good reference books are worth 10000 times their weight in satisfied customers.  Maybe I'll splash out, though I don't use C# an awful lot.

Comment: Writing just the Differentials from 4  to 5 is a great idea.  IMHO - a pesron doesnt need to go through the whole book and filters : " oh , this I know from c#4 , and that I dont know , so is it from c#4 or c#5 ?" so again , its a great idea !  (p.s. a person who buy c#5 differentials , and sees he has a lot of gaps , will buy also the c#4...so  , again its a great idea.

Comment: Jon why do i need the while loop ? An if condition is also working .... So why the while is there ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Imagine the monitor is pulsed, and the owner exits the thread... but before any of the waiting threads are woken, another thread grabs the lock and sets the signal to `false`. One waiting thread will still wake - even though the event has been reset. (It also helps with spurious wakes, although I don't know whether those occur on Windows.)

Comment: Sorry jon maybe im not seeing it , but if another thread changed the flag to false so the "if condition"' will still make the thread wait

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, the waiting thread will have evaluated the `if` condition *before it started waiting`. That's the whole point - you want it to evaluate the condition again when it's finished waiting.

Comment: Jon are you telling me that the pulse mechanism was designed to go to the "loop section " of the waiting thread ? So it can reevaluate itself ? Also , when a thread waits and pulsed , what is the first line which is running again in order to reevaluate ? The beginning of the lock ? The line in which he stopped ? Do you see where im getting confused here ? Thanks jon and sorry for ....

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The waiting thread has to reacquire the lock, then execution continues from just after the `Wait()` call - as is natural, given that it's just a method call. So if you want the condition to be re-evaluated (as you should) you need a loop.